# Jenkins - Getting parameters used in job A build as active choice parameters for job B build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I would like to get a parameter used in latest successful build of job A(lets call it build A)
to be available as part of an active choice parameters when trying to "build with parameters" job B

The process i am attempting is as follows:
Create a docker image in job C
Post build job C > build job A with docker image name as parameter
Attempt to "build with parameters" job B with the Job A's last successful build parameter as active choices parameter.

in job B, i added a active choices parameter, with the following script:

Groovy script:

```
def build = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName('BuildB').getLastSuccessfulBuild()
def String myVar= build.getEnvironment(TaskListener.NULL).get('TEST_NAME')
return [myVar, '1']
```

while the script does work interdependently in Jenkins Script Console, it does not work when attempting to "build with parameters", and it keeps going to the fallback script.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you share the logs

Comment: @DanTe see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74977319/16090108
managed to solve it by using different command

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by using this code:

```
try{
def build = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('BuildB').getLastSuccessfulBuild().getBuildVariables()["TEST_NAME"]
return [build]
} catch (Exception e){return [e.getMessage()]}
```